# How to set the tab size for a specific kernel in Jupyterlab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, indentation, jupyter-lab

In Jupyterlab, It is possible to change the tab space for each constituent of a Jupyter notebook through Settings `->` Advanced Settings Editor `->` Notebook option and editing the `tabSize` attribute. However, this changes the tab size for the notebooks for every kernel.

I would like to have 2 tab spaces for Scala kernel and 4 tab spaces (the default) for the rest. It such a setting possible?

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

No, but you should file an issue about it on the [Jupyterlab github](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues), since the devs are pretty responsive to this kind of thing. For example, I got them to implement a way to turn off the crazy-making `autoClosingBrackets` behavior in all of the editors just by asking nicely.

## Details

The definitions/defaults for all of the notebook settings are currently implemented in [this json file in the Jupyterlab source](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/master/packages/notebook-extension/schema/tracker.json). The relevant `tabSize` setting can be found inside the `codeCellConfig` field, the description of which is:

> The configuration for all code cells.

and it does indeed apply to *all* code cells, regardless of kernel/language.

Comment: How can one apply the content of the 'tracker.json' file you are referring to? 'edit.json' or 'notebook.json' in .\user\.jupyter\nbconfig folder ?